# Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule Service Provider initiated sample code

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Is there sample c# code (not web.config) to do a Service Provide initiated call and also receiving the response from the Identity provider for HttpModule? I have a web forms application. The code below has mixed MVC stuff (which doesn't work). Thanks in advance.

```
var idp = Options.FromConfiguration.IdentityProviders.Default;
var defaultDestination = idp.SingleSignOnServiceUrl;

string UriString = "http://localhost:49826/sso";
Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.HttpRequestData request = ToHttpRequestData(context);

var result = new SignInCommand().Run(request, Options.FromConfiguration);

var httpResponseBase = new HttpResponseWrapper(context.Response);
result.ApplyCookies(httpResponseBase, false);
```